# laravel unit Testing getting "Expected status code 200 but received 302. Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 302" trying to learn unit testing

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, routes, controller

i'm trying to do a unit testing for my code but having a hard time understand what i need to do for code testing, this is my first time using stackoverflow so im sorry if i asked something in confusing way (im using laravel 7.3)

this is my code for testing

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    public function user_can_login()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create([
            'email'    => 'username@example.net',
            'password' => 'password',
        ]);

        $this->visit('/login');

        // Submit form login with email dan password
        $this->submitForm('Login', [
            'email'    => 'username@example.net',
            'password' => 'password',
        ]);

        // get redirect ke url '/home' (login sukses).
        $this->seePageIs('/');

    }
}
```

im trying to do a login test with this code. but im getting error "Expected status code 200 but received 302. Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 302."

and this is my route and controller

route :

```
Route::middleware(['authcheck'])->group(function() {
    Route::get('/login', 'AuthController@index');
    Route::post('/do-login', 'AuthController@doLogin');
});
```

this is my controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Models\Admin;
use App\Models\User;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function doLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $checkAdmin = User::where('email', $request->email)
            ->get()->first();
        if (!empty($checkAdmin)) {
            if (Hash::check($request->password, $checkAdmin->password)) {
                $request->session()->put('auth_user', $checkAdmin);
                if($checkAdmin->roles == '5'){
                    return redirect('/list-e-tiket');
                }else{
                    return redirect('/');
                }
                
            }else{
                return redirect('/login')->with('error', 'Password is wrong.!');
            }
        }else{
            return redirect('/login')->with('error', 'Username not registered.!');
        }
    }
}
```

is there something that i can fix to enable me to do a Unit Testing ?

im expecting an error if the example doesnt follow whats inside the database, and if i put email and pass using something that already in the database it wil put out an OK

Comment: If you are testing routes it is better to put it in the `Feature` test instead of `Unit` test

Comment: i see thanks for the information, but what if i want to test function (Ex : public function login) (does unit mean testing the function?) do i need to seperate it in new laravel project?

Comment: Yes that's what unit test means. You are testing a block of code which is the function whether it works as it is intended or not.

Comment: @NAK so, you have to extend `TestCase` from Laravel -> `\Tests\TestCase` not `\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` because you have nothing available (Laravel's TestCase starts the framework and stuff). And you want to do a `Feature` test, you want to test a request here, so that is a feature test, not a unit test. Change that and tell us if the error changed